# Absolutize possibly non-existent path in bash? (linux)

Tags: linux, bash, path

There are many instances on SO where people have asked how best to absolutize a path in bash, but I haven't found any that deal with absolutizing non-yet-existent paths.

The `cd $1 && pwd` method does not work at all for non-existent paths.

The `readlink -f $1` method will only work for one level of non-existence;  that is, it will work for "`~/sdkjf`", but not for "`~/sdkjf/qweuio`"

Ideally, I would like a method that would expand the latter to `/home/username/sdkjf/qweuio` ... and would also do similar transforms for ./ and ../

Can you recommend a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`readlink -m $1`

From the manpage:

```
  -m, --canonicalize-missing
          canonicalize  by  following  every  symlink  in every component of the given 
          name recursively, without requirements on components existence
```

Comment: Sorry for answering my own question... I don't know why I didn't notice this in the manpage, previously.  :)